# Is there any inheritance between two process with pid 50142 and 150142?

Tags: linux, process, fork, parent-child, pid

I am using a tool and monitoring its resource usage; I got this at certain point with 'top' command, the 1st and 2nd entry here with pid 50142 and 150142 respectively are the one I am interested in, would any one tell me if these two processes are related? given the numerical resemblance and the fact that they both launch by the same application?[image]

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is an inheritance between those 2 process, but here is some stuff you can do to check that.

You can check the PPID of those 2 process to see if they have a common parent process, if they have, yes it is likely they are related `ps -o pid,ppid,cmd -p 50142,150142`

You can also check the process tree with `pstree -p` and look for 50142 and 150142 you will see if they are part of the same process hierarchy.

If you have access to the code source of the program correspnding to those process you can also see if they are linked.

Comment: you are right, I can't jump to that conclusion with pid; also, 50142 is gone now, so no way 
 to find out in this session, any means to log the 'top' command output? wish to keep a record on this as I just found out how to have ppid field on its output;

Comment: You can do top -b -n 1 > top-output.txt for saving the output of top one time, or you can do a cron to do it like each minutes, with this entry * * * * * top -b -n 1 >> /var/log/top-output.log